# Spatial with SparkSQL/Python in Synapse Spark Pool using apache-sedona?

Tags: pyspark, geospatial, azure-synapse, kryo

I would like to run spatial queries on large data sets; e.g. geopandas would be too slow.
Inspiration I found here: https://anant-sharma.medium.com/apache-sedona-geospark-using-pyspark-e60485318fbe

In Spark Pool of Synapse Analytics I prepared (via Azure Portal):

## Apache Spark Pool / Settings / Packages / Requirement files:

requirement.txt:

```
azure-storage-file-share
geopandas
apache-sedona
```

## Apache Spark Pool / Settings / Packages / Workspace packages:

```
geotools-wrapper-geotools-24.1.jar
sedona-sql-3.0_2.12-1.2.0-incubating.jar
```

## Apache Spark Pool / Settings / Packages / Spark configuration

config.txt:

```
spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryo.registrator org.apache.sedona.core.serde.SedonaKryoRegistrator
```

In Pyspark Notebook

```
print(spark.version)
print(spark.conf.get("spark.kryo.registrator"))
print(spark.conf.get("spark.serializer"))
```

The output was:

```
3.1.2.5.0-58001107
org.apache.sedona.core.serde.SedonaKryoRegistrator
org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

Then I tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from sedona.register import SedonaRegistrator  
from sedona.utils import SedonaKryoRegistrator, KryoSerializer
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Sedona App").config("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.getName).config("spark.kryo.registrator", SedonaKryoRegistrator.getName).getOrCreate()
SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
```

But it failed:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o636.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: **Failed to register classes with Kryo**

A simple check that stuff is correctly installed would probaly allow this:

```
%%sql
SELECT ST_Point(0,0);
```

***Please help with getting the spatial functions registered in pyspark running in Synapse notebook!***

Answer (score 1):

As per the repro from my end, I'm able to successfully run the above commands without any issue.

I just installed the `requirement.txt` file contains `apache-sedona` and downloaded below two jar files:

- [sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12–1.0.0-incubating.jar](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.sedona/sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12/1.0.0-incubating/jar)
- [geotools-wrapper-geotools-24.0.jar](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.datasyslab/geotools-wrapper/geotools-24.0/jar)

Note: `config.txt` file is not required.

[image]